# If I launch a coin, will it always fall down?

Tags: gravity

I was running in the university aisle (I was late for the statistics lesson) when I heard: "In normal condition there is a possiblity that if you launch a coin instead of falling down it'll go up". Is it true?

From my basic physic knowledge the coin will have to change its mass from positive to negative, correct? What is the possibility?

Comment: More on [negative mass](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22negative+mass%22+gravity).

Comment: I think what the "story"-teller was referring to is the (astronomically small) chance of classical mechanics suddenly failing on a macroscopic object due to quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Danu could you be more specific? How can I calculate that probability?

Comment: @Tinwor You can't, really, in practice. Just know that it will be *ridiculously small* (it literally will never happen)

Answer (score 1):

The equation for the force of gravity is:
$$
GMm/r^2
$$
Where G is the gravitational constant, M is the mass of the gravitational source being looked at (in this case the Earth), m is the mass of the coin and r is the distance from the gravitational source.

Gravitational potential energy is defined as the work needed to move a mass from an infinite distance to a finite distance away from the source of gravity, the equation for this is:
$$
\int_∞^rGMm/r^2dr=-GMm/r
$$
This can be compared to the equation for kinetic energy to find where they cancel out. When they cancel you reach what is called "escape velocity"; at this speed the coin will go up and not come back down because, mathematically, the distance it travels before it stops accelerating is infinite. The equation for this can be worked out like this:
$$mv^2/2=GMm/r$$
$$v^2/2=GM/r$$
$$v^2=2GM/r$$
$$v=\sqrt(2GM/r)$$

Comment: I know what is the "escape velocity" but it's not what I mean. If I launch the coin it will never reach the escape velocity. I think is correlated with quantum physics as Danu said. Anyway +1 for the answer